# If the transformation T is an isometry, then the column vectors of [T] form an orthonormal set.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, isometry

I'm not sure how to attack this problem at all. An isometric transformation preserves length of vectors, but I can't make any connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Apply to the standard basis, which is orthonormal.  You see, $T$, since defined on a finite dimensional vector space, also preserves angles, by the usual definition of isometry.

Comment: I see that $T(e_1)$, $T(e_2)$, etc are unit vectors but how does this tell me anything about the column vectors of $[T]$?

Comment: Those are the first two columns.  Etc...

Comment: Try applying a matrix to a standard basis vector.  You get the $n$-th column, where $n$ is which basis vector it is.